# Extraneous Property Error : Fb:page_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parameters

I want to add a like button to my webpage but the number of likes stays on '38' for each page. I used the debugger and here is the result :
Extraneous Property :   Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id.

If I delete the line 'fb:page_id' the debugger gives me two error with the 'og:url' and 'og:title'!

Here is my meta code. I don't understand what is wrong.

```
<title><?php echo $song_title;?> | NightTunes</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="NightTunes"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="song"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://NightTunes.org/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://NightTunes.org/images/logo.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NightTunes"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="793649824"/>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="160941893927000" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="NightTunes' goals are to support EDM artists from the industry leading names to the up and comers. We endeavor to bring to our readers first-rate news about releases, events, stories and so forth.">
<meta name="keywords" content="nighttunes,livechat,albin,myers,swedish,chat,house,live-chat,live,music,electro,dubstep,myback,john,dahlback, tristan, garner, avicii, house, music" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.NightTunes.org/images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="image_src" href="campus/upload/<?php echo $meta_image;?>"/>
```

Help Help !!! :'(

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't have a page_id on an object of type 'song' - the 'page_id' tag is {edit: was, until December 2011} for claiming a website/domain for analytics purposes.
2. The og:url tag must point to the URL you want to be liked if a user likes or shares the page - in most cases this will be the same URL that the Like button is on.
3. Any other errors can easily be explained (at this point) by the fact that it looks like your og:url tag is pointing to the root of your domain, which may not have the correct tags